# Table cell to count rows in other table

Tags: sql, t-sql

I'm not entirely sure if I'm even going about this in the right manner.
MVC+EF site so i could do this in the controller but I would prefer it in the DB if possible.

I have two tables. One contains entries and one contains a list of members. I want the list of members to have a column that contains the count of how many times the member name appears in the list of entries. Can I do this in the definition of the table itself?

I know this query works:

```
select count(*)
from dbo.Entries
where dbo.Entries.AssignedTo = 'Bob Smith'
```

But is there any way of doing this? What is the correct syntax?

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Members] (
[ID]    INT            IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
[Name]  NVARCHAR (100) NOT NULL,
[Email] NVARCHAR (500) NOT NULL,
[Count] INT = select count(*) from dbo.Entries where dbo.Entries.AssignedTo = [Name]
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([ID] ASC)
```

I've done some searching and have tried a few different syntax's but I'm completely lost at this point so if anyone can get me headed in the correct direction I would really appreciate it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can't create a computed column that depends on data from a different table.  I think you can create what is called a materialized view  (based on your query)  that will do what you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could create `Members` as a view combining both the `Entries` data and another table. (Warning: Syntax not tested)

```
CREATE TABLE [_member_data] (
  [ID]   INT IDENTITY(1, 1) NOT NULL,
  [Name]  NVARCHAR (100) NOT NULL,
  [Email] NVARCHAR (500) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([ID] ASC)
);

CREATE VIEW [dbo].[Members] AS
  SELECT ID, Name, Email, COUNT(*)
    FROM _member_data JOIN dbo.Entries ON [Name] = [AssignedTo]
    GROUP BY 1, 2, 3;
```

It is possible to take this even further with triggers/rules that rewrite attempted inserts into `Members` as inserts to the appropriate backing table.  But to get the kind of expressive information that you are looking for, you really want to explore using a view.

Comment: so without triggers/rules this would not dynamically change with both the entries and members tables?

Comment: This will dynamically update as you add data to `_member_data` or `Entries`.  But you would need to add a trigger if you wanted something like `INSERT INTO Members...` to work, as opposed to doing it the "manual" way of `INSERT INTO _member_data`.